# React - Modify component style via javascript or css?

Tags: reactjs

Is it better to style your components in the component's .jsx file, or in a separate .css file? Also, is there a performance difference?

Comment: See if the docs answer your question: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html#can-i-use-inline-styles

Answer (score 1):

Having a separate CSS file makes "styling" the component more... discrete than modifying the in-line styles. It also makes it possible to combine the changes more easily later with something like SASS/SCSS or similar tools.

On the other hand, the disadvantage of having a separate stylesheet is the increased difficulty in doing live modifications to the style.

Then there are tools like [Radium (for React.js)](https://formidable.com/open-source/radium/) that lets you manipulate style objects as JavaScript objects.

It really depends on your programming style, and "corporate guidelines", if any.